# Getting ClassCastException on implementing ListView in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I am implementing a List view using custom Layout. I am making an api call and the data is getting set into **City.class** object.
Actually I am getting the List populated with City object data. But when i put an OnListItemClick event on the List i am getting exception.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.stata.mobile.android.dao.City
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at com.stata.mobile.android.ui.NearMeListFragment.onListItemClick(MyListFragment.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at com.stata.mobile.android.ui.NearMeListFragment$1.onItemClick(MyListFragment.java:78)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

My Fragment class code is like.

```
  public class MyListFragment  extends Fragment{
           @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.near_me, container,false);
            listView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    onListItemClick((ListView) parent, view, position, id);
                }
            });

            new MyTask().execute();
            return view;
        }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        City city = ((City) l.getItemAtPosition(position));   // At this line i am getting the exception
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), NearMeDetailActivity.class).putExtra("nearmecity",city));
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out why it's happening. As soon as i am clicking on any item on the List i am getting this classCastException. I want to get that particular object and wants to show new activity where i can give the details of the city class

Adapter class

```
public class NearMeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
     private Activity activity;
    private List<City> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

 public MyListAdapter(Activity a, List<City> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

 public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

}
```

Comment: Problem is your `Adapter` class ... `getItem` method returns `Integer` instead `City`

Comment: @Selvin .. i have added the adapter class also . so might me i have made some mistake.. once please check and let me correct it

Comment: why don't you guys using ArrayAdapter<T> instead BaseAdapter? all you have to do is to override  getView method ... instead activity inside ArrayAdapter you should use getContext() and to get item at getItem(at) ... to correct your code take a look at ArrayAdapter source ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the exception is clear that you have created an array of `Integer`. `getItemAtPosition` returns the element at position in your dataset. If you are adapter is made of `City` it will return an object of City.

Edit:

Your error is here:

```
  public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
  }
```

it should be

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}
```

Comment: I have added the adapter class also .. can you figure what might have gone wrong

Comment: Thanx @blackbelt.. it got solved... thanx again for your quick reply

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as a string then pass the intent.

> String city = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();